# ¿Porque me aparece contenido html en la data de un pedido AJAX?

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente pedido ajax:

```js
    $("#exit").click(function(e) {
    
        $.ajax({

   
       
            url: "/basico/logout.php",
       
           

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
           success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if (data==0){
     
                alert("debe cerrar la caja");
            
        //   window.location.href="index.php";
            }else{
                alert("session cerrada");
               // location.href="index.php";
            }
           
        }
});
  
    });
```

Y el logout.php:

```
  <?php
  session_start(); //mantiene activa la sesion
 $iduser=$_SESSION['userid'];
 $idsesion=$_SESSION['idsesion'];
  include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/basico/models/claseLogin.php'); 
 $L1=new Login();
 $cerrocaja=$L1->cerrarSesion($iduser,$idsesion);

 if ($cerrocaja==false){
    echo false;
 }else{
 echo true;
 session_destroy(); //destruye la sesion iniciada
 header('Location: ./'); //posicionamos la cabecera
 exit(0); //salida
} ?>
```

el Metodo cerrar sesion consulta un campo de una tabla si dice "n":

```
     public function cerrarSesion($iduser,$idsesion){
      try
        {

    $conexion = Conexion::singleton_conexion();
    $stm=$conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM sesiones WHERE iduser=".$iduser."AND idsesion=".$idsesion.";");

     $stm->execute();
    $fila=$stm->fetch();

      if ($fila[6]=='n'){

        return false;
      }else{
        return true;
      }
    }catch(Exception $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
  }      
 }
```

Y ademas me da siempre verdadera la comprobacion, esto se debe a que al pedido ajax si hago un log de consola trae contenido html. Es decir como puedo hacer un pedido ajax para comprobar si tiene true o false para saber si cerro la caja o no.

Comment: No entendí la razón del problema que estás teniendo, podrías explicar mejor?

Comment: el pedido ajax trae contenido html del index no se porque entonces no puedo comprobar si es true or false para mostrar el alert, siempre me da igual

Comment: ah, pues, en tu php qué te regresa exactamente? podrías pegar el resultado aquí en un comentario?

Comment: Encontre el problema, falta un espacio antes del AND en la consulta, por eso retornaba mal..Gracias man..